# How to translate a first-order logic sentence into a restriction in Protègè with string matching?

Tags: string-matching, ontology, protege, first-order-logic

I'm tring to build an ontology to infer some informations about a domain classification and a terminology, but I'm experiencing some conceptual difficulties.

Let me explain the problem. In Protègè 4.1 i created 6 subclasses of Thing: Concept, conceptTitle, ConceptSynonym (for the classification) and Term, TermTitle, TermSynonym (for the terminology). I also have created hasConceptTitle, hasConceptSynonym, hasTermTitle and hasTermSynonym object relationships (with some constrint) to say that every Concept has one (and only one) title, and may have some synonyms, and every Term has one (and only one) title and some synonyms. Both Concept and Term have another relationship isA, giving to the classification a DAG/tree structure, while the terminology has a lattice structure (in other words, a term may be a subclass of more than one term).

Here comes the problem: I would like to create a subclass of Concept, let's say "MappedConcept"),  which should be the set of mapped concepts, that is the set of concepts which  have the title equals to a term's title, or it has a synonym equals to a term's title or has a synonym that is equal to a synonym of a term.
In the first-order logic, this set may be expressed as:

```
∀x∃y( ∃z((hasConceptTitle(x,z) ∧ hasTermTitle(y,z)) ∨
      ∃z((hasConceptTitle(x,z) ∧ hasTermSynonym(y,z)) ∨
      ∃z((hasConceptSynonym(x,z) ∧ hasTermTitle(y,z)) ∨
      ∃z((hasConceptSynonym(x,z) ∧ hasTermSynonym(y,z)) )
```

How can I obtain this? Defining data properties for "ConceptTitle", "ConceptSynonym", "TermTitle" and "TermSynonym"? And how to describe the string matches? 
Maybe those 4 classes should be just data properties of Concept and Term classes?
I read the practical guide of Matthew Horridge several times, but I can't the practical ideas I have on my mind into an ongology in Protègè.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you "express" with the FOL formula is not a set. It is an expression that is either true or false, depending on how you interpret `hasConceptTitle`, `hasConceptSynonym`, `hasTermTitle` and `hasTermSynonym`.

Comment: @AntoineZimmermann Thanks for your answer, I expressed bad my idea. However, having a simple object relationship "isMapped" with Concept as domain and Term as Range, how can I restrict it to classify Concept in a subclass, MappedConcept, that satisfies that "expression"?

Comment: Using FOL formula is not a problem, and you do want to define a set. But you have to say what is the thing in the set in the formula. I suspect that you would like to define the set of things `x` such that there exists a thing `y` such that there is a `z` etc... Is it correct?

Comment: @AntoineZimmermann: Thanks again for your support. I would like to define the set of Things x such that x is a Concept, such that exist Thing y that y is a Term, and x has the ConceptTitle z and y has the Term title z, or x has a ConceptSynonym z and y has TermTitle z., ...
Maybe my problem is that I come from programming languages where I do something like if( ((Concept) x).getTitle() == ((Term) y).getTitle() ) then print("These objects are mapped");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot do this in OWL 2 DL nor in Protégé, which is an editor for OWL 2 DL, because, as far as I can tell, it seems necessary to introduce the inverse of a datatype property, which is forbidden in OWL 2 DL. However, it's possible in OWL Full, and some DL reasoners may even be able to deal with it. Here, in Turtle:

```
<MappedConcept>  a  owl:Class;
    owl:equivalentTo  [
        a  owl:Class;
        owl:unionOf (
            [
                a  owl:Restriction;
                owl:onProperty  <hasConceptTitle>;
                owl:someValuesFrom  [
                    a  owl:Restriction;
                    owl:onProperty  [ owl:inverseOf <hasTermTitle> ];
                    owl:someValuesFrom  <Term>
                ]
            ] [
                a  owl:Restriction;
                owl:onProperty  <hasConceptTitle>;
                owl:someValuesFrom  [
                    a  owl:Restriction;
                    owl:onProperty  [ owl:inverseOf <hasTermSynonym> ];
                    owl:someValuesFrom  <Term>
                ]
            ] [
                a  owl:Restriction;
                owl:onProperty  <hasConceptSynonym>;
                owl:someValuesFrom  [
                    a  owl:Restriction;
                    owl:onProperty  [ owl:inverseOf <hasTermSynonym> ];
                    owl:someValuesFrom  <Term>
                ]
            ] [
                a  owl:Restriction;
                owl:onProperty  <hasConceptSynonym>;
                owl:someValuesFrom  [
                    a  owl:Restriction;
                    owl:onProperty  [ owl:inverseOf <hasTermTitle> ];
                    owl:someValuesFrom  <Term>
                ]
            ]
        )
    ] .
```

You can also do it without OWL, with a rule language for instance. The rules would look closer to how you would do it in programming languages. In SWRL:

```
hasConceptTitle(?x,?z), hasTermTitle(?y,?z) -> MappedConcept(?x)
hasConceptTitle(?x,?z), hasTermSynonym(?y,?z) -> MappedConcept(?x)
hasConceptSynonym(?x,?z), hasTermTitle(?y,?z) -> MappedConcept(?x)
hasConceptSynonym(?x,?z), hasTermSynonym(?y,?z) -> MappedConcept(?x)
```

Comment: Really thank you Antoine, your suggestions are really valuable.  I'll change my approach for solving this problem. Thank you again, good Christmas and happy New Year!